# Is there a built-in function that quickly counts how many bits an int takes up?

Tags: c++, built-in

I am trying to count how many bits an `int` takes up,e.g. `count(10)=4`,`count(7)=3`,`count(127)=7` etc.
I have tried brute-forcing(`<<`ing a `1` until it's strictly bigger than the number) and using `floor(log2(v))+1`,but both are too slow for my needs.
I know that there exists a `__builtin_popcnt` function that quickly count how many `1`s there are in an `int`,but I had trouble finding a built-in that fits my applictions,is there no such function or have I overlooked something?

Edit:I'm working with `g++` version `9.3.0`
Edit2:mediocrevegetable1's answer was chosen because it was the only one usable with `g++` at the time.However,future readers may also try out chris's answer for better compatibility or in hopes that the compiler will give a more efficient implementation.

Comment: Are you working only with uints?

Comment: Yes,the number is promised to be `>=0`

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages, which have very different support for doing what you want. Please pick one of them. Also any symbol beginning with double underscore should be considered a non-portable compiler-specific symbol (with a few exceptions).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out,removed the C tag accordingly.

Comment: Did you try checking the biggest 2^n that fits in your number? because n+1 will be the answer. Don't know about a build in one.

Comment: What's the range of values that needs to be handled by `count(N)`?  Does `N` cover the full `unsigned int` range or is it more limited?

Comment: Responding to Ethen.S. I have tried this approach, it gives the right answer but is too slow for my needs :(

Comment: Responding to G.M. Almost,it covers a range from 0 to `2^31-1`

Comment: FWIW, I would fully expect the speed to be equal between my answer and the accepted one. It's quite likely that the accepted answer is really close to the actual implementation of `bit_width`.

Comment: Good point,modified the wording of the question to reflect it and the fact that this has better compatibility.My sincerest thanks for all people that helped me in this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GCC built-in function `__builtin_clz`, which gives the leading zero's:

```
#include <climits>

constexpr unsigned bit_space(unsigned n)
{
    return (sizeof n * CHAR_BIT) - __builtin_clz(n);
}
```

Comment: You're using a non-standard and non-portable function. Might be worth to mention which compiler it's specific for.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP specified their compiler, so I thought that was implied. Though I'll just edit to clarify that `__builtin_clz` is a GCC builtin.

Answer (score 10):

C++20 added [`std::bit_width`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_width) ([live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8dG5Yzj5T)):

```
#include <bit>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout 
      << std::bit_width(10u) << ' ' // 4
      << std::bit_width(7u) << ' ' // 3
      << std::bit_width(127u); // 7
}
```

With Clang trunk and, for example, `-O3 -march=skylake`, a function doing nothing but calling `bit_width` produces the following assembly:

```
count(unsigned int):
    lzcnt   ecx, edi
    mov     eax, 32
    sub     eax, ecx
    ret
```

There are a number of similar functions in this new `<bit>` header as well. You can [see them all here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit).

Comment: Seeing the edit to the question, it doesn't look like GCC 9.3 implemented this yet, but the answer should be useful to future visitors regardless, or in the future with a compiler upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

you can use asm

```
int index;
int value = 0b100010000000;
asm("bsr %1, %0":"=a"(index):"a"(value)); // now index equals 11
```

this method returns zero-based index of the last set bit
which means it will also return zero if no bit is set
to get around this, one can first check if `value` is not zero
if `value` is zero that means no bit is set
if `value` is not zero that means `index + 1` is the number of bits used by `value`

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard library function for this.
No need to write anything yourself.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/count

```
#include <cassert>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<32> value = 0b10010110;
    auto count = value.count();
    assert(count == 4);
}
```

After the feedback below, that this was the incorrect answer.
I don't know if there is a build in function.
But this compile time constexpr will give the same result.

```
#include <cassert>

static constexpr auto bits_needed(unsigned int value)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    for (; value > 0; value >>= 1, ++n);
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    assert(3 == bits_needed(7));
    assert(4 == bits_needed(10));
    assert(4 == bits_needed(9));
    assert(16 == bits_needed(65000));
}
```

Comment: The OP isn't asking for the number of bits that are set. They want the number of bits needed to represent the value (8 bits in your example).